# Join Query with multiple tables in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, join, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have implemented @ManyToMany relationship but with extra table using @OneToMany and @ManyToOne between **User** ,**Roles** , **Permissions** and  extra tables are "**UserRole**","**RolePermissions**"

one user can have multiple roles and ,one role can also have multiple permissions . I have to get permissions of users on base of roles . so i wrote a query that is working fine

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Permission p INNER JOIN p.roles rp INNER JOIN rp.role r INNER JOIN r.users ur INNER JOIN ur.user u WHERE u.id=:userId")
List<Permission> findAllUserRolePermissions(@Param("userId") long userId);
```

this query looks lengthy,I want to make it short or optimize it if possible.

Entities are Following here

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class User {

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = UserRole.class, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<UserRole> roles;


//Role
@Entity
@Table(name = "Role")
public class Role implements Serializable {
@OneToMany(targetEntity = UserRole.class, mappedBy = "role", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<UserRole> users;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = RolePermission.class, mappedBy = "role", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<RolePermission> rolePermissions;

//Use_Role  
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_ROLE")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserRole {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private Role role;



//Permission

@Entity
@Table(name = "PERMISSION")
public class Permission {

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = RolePermission.class, mappedBy = "permission", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<RolePermission> roles;


//Role_Permission
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLE_PERMISSION")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class RolePermission {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private Role role;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERMISSION_ID")
    private Permission permission;
```

what i want ?

1)is this query fine ? or can be improved if yes then how ?

2)can i achieve this using  spring data interface methods like following

```
List<Permission> findAllUserRolePermissions(List<Role> roles);// all 
permissions by roles of user
```

3)any resource to learn spring data jpa join queries

any suggestion would be appreciated.thanks

Comment: why all of the INNER JOINs when you don't use the aliases? That isn't the way to get those fields fetched

Comment: so which join should i use ?

Comment: To request the JPA provider to FETCH the fields? FETCH JOIN. But then any JPA documentation would tell you that

Comment: i'm fetching fields on clustered or relation mappings ,same result would be come if i use only JOIN .

Comment: Nope. Doing a plain JOIN just says to JOIN. It doesn't say to FETCH (which is a HINT to the JPA provider to fetch the relation). Clearly you also have entity graphs to allow fetching, also in the JPA spec

Comment: can you please provide any related article link, i'm confused about join in multiple tables in spring data JPA .